# UIImage and prepareforSegue doesn´t pass the image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, segue

I would like that appeared the Image on the second view with this but I can´t see any photo I don´t know why. I did this:

**FirstClassViewController.m:**

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCover"]) {
            MovieImageViewController *photo = [segue destinationViewController];       
            photo.cover.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"helloWorld.jpg"];
            }
         }
```

**SecondClassViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self cover]; 
}
```

The **cover** is a property **UIImageView** that I created on the **SecondClassViewController**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `prepareForSegue:sender:` the outlets from your destinationViewController are not set yet. This means that your `photo.cover` property is still nil.

What you can do is create a `UIImage` property on your `MovieImageViewController` and do something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCover"]) {
            MovieImageViewController *photo = [segue destinationViewController];       
            photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"helloWorld.jpg"];
        }
}
```

and on your `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.cover.image = self.image;
}
```

Comment: but self.image don´t work because it isn´t a property

Comment: and photo.image shouldn´t be because image it isn´t a property, the property is cover and it is in MovieImage

Comment: that's why I said that "What you can do is **create** a UIImage property..."

Comment: Why the UIImage property isn't nil? It's only because it's not an outlet? Or is something related with the View hierarchy?

Comment: it is initially nil, but then you set it on `prepareForSegue` (`photo.image = ...`). So, on `-viewDidLoad`, you set the `cover.image` to be `self.image`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that "cover" is an image view property of your MovieImageViewController class? If so, don't do that.

You should treat another view controllers views as private.

Instead, set up an image property in your MovieImageViewController class. Set THAT in your prepareForSegue method, and then in your MovieImageViewController's viewWillAppear:animated method, install the image into your "cover" image view. Problem solved.

EDIT: To clarify

Add the following to the header (.h) file for your MovieImageViewController class:

```
@interface MovieImageViewController

//This property is the line to add
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *coverImage;

//your other stuff goes here.

@end
```

Then in your .m file:

```
@implementation MovieImageViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear: animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear: animated];
  //Add the following code to your viewWillAppear:animated method
  if (self.coverImage != nil)
     self.cover.image = self.coverImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, the cover is a UIImageView property of my MovieImageVC, but I don´t understand you sorry..